# How to display test images with prediction

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I want display my test images with predicted label for it.

```
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: images32, y_: one_hot_lables})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: test_images32, y_: T_one_hot_lables}))
```

I only print result, but i want display every images in test_images32 and predicted label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This naturally depends on the shape of the data, but for general deep learning problems I use the following method using matplotlib. You might want to extend this using `plt.ion()` to make this interactive and wait after each image shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

predictions = sess.run(y, {feed_dict={x: test_images32}})
for i, image in enumerate(test_images32):
     plt.imshow(image) # depending on being RGB or gray this might need to be reshaped
     print(np.argmax(predictions[i]))
```